# What is the right way to print escaped strings, and to hide backslashes on users end?

Tags: php, laravel-4, wordpress-theming, stripslashes

I'm building a website using Laravel 4. I'm using triple "{" while printing data from the database, or data that can be user manipulated but I have a dilemma here. When special characters are used they are escaped with a "\", but I don't want the "\" to appear on the site.

So my question is how to print these strings the right way? I know I can use stripslashes to remove the "\", but is this safe? The slashes are added there for a reason so just stripping them would't be a problem? Is there a better/safer way to achieve this?

Note: I'm not asking for a Laravel approach only, I'm also open to pure php suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have ``\`` in your data, you're doing it wrong. Your pure data should never contain escape sequences of any kind. It most likely means you're escaping one time too many somewhere.

Comment: I'm escaping only once, on printing using laravel's "{{{ }}}". From what I know, Laravel handles the escaping while inserting into DB or while querying a DB. But the "\" appears even if I don't escape on printing. May this have something to do with my php/apache configuration? Or with Laravel cnfiguration?

Comment: When you look at your data in the database using phpmyadmin or some other non-Laravel admin utility, does it contain the backslashes? If so, maybe you have a problem with Magic Quotes? (Google for that)

Comment: @deceze Yes, the backslashes are also added in database. I disabled Magic Quotes already (there's no trace of them in php_info() and also get_magic_quotes_gpc() returns null) and still I haven't found the source of this problem :(.

Comment: Then you'll have to dig deeper. Something is introducing backslashes when it's unwanted.

Comment: @deceze You were right! I had to dig even more deeper. :)) Thanks for trying to help me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of this after all. In the public folder of this website we also have wordpress installed to be used as a CMS for our blog section of the website. It seems that WordPress was altering the $_POST/$_GET variables.

The solution for this was to capture the $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST variables in a temporary array before the wordpress is initialized in **public/index.php** and reassign them the values from that array after wordpress is initialized.

```
$tmp = array($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST);
```

-

```
/**
*   Include wordpress
*/
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require __DIR__.'/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
```

-

```
list($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST) = $tmp;
```